# Restore a minimzed window with a terminal command?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I am using this command to "activate" (focus) a unfocused window:

```
xdotool windowactivate --sync $WINDOW_ID
```

But, this only works if the window is not minimzed. So I figured I need a separate command to "restore" the window from minimzed state.

Is there such a command?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here, perhaps others find it useful:

`wmctrl -x -a "$WINDOW_ID"` is able to "restore" a minimized window.

The WINDOW_ID can be found by listing open windows: `wmctrl -lxp`

E.g. `wmctrl -lxp` returns

> 0x04800050  0 54543  code.Code             pop-os common - Visual Studio Code

Then "code.Code" is the WINDOW_ID:

```
wmctrl -x -a "code.Code"
```